# How to execute SPARQL query for multiple RDF files?

Tags: rdf, jena, semantic-web, sesame

I have got **44** `.ttl` files with the total memory of **117 GB**. I'm curious about the efficient method for executing SPARQL query for all `.ttl` files in real time. I tried to combine them, but loading the model takes a lot of time in `Apache Jena` as well as combinations. So, what should be the most efficient way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Load them once into a triplestore such as Jena's TDB.  You can do it into one big graph or into separate named graphs depending on needs.

This saves all the data parsing time when you want to execute a query.

Comment: They are DBpedia files, should use DBpedia endpoint? Which would be more efficient?

Answer (score 2):

I have not used Jena; but this is what I'd do if I were using Sesame.

1. Avoid relying on DBpedia endpoint if this is going to be an enterprise application. Publicly available SPARQL endpoints are sometimes down for maintenance. You will not be able to execute your queries when that happens.
2. You can either load the .ttl files to your triplestore, or use INSERT or INSERT DATA features of SPARQL 1.1 with SERVICE clause to upload the data to your triplestore directly from DBpedia.
3. Store all the data in a single graph if possible. Running federated queries is computationally more expensive and given the large dataset, it's probably going to be a bit of an issue.
4. To differentiate the sources, you can define the 'context' (graph name) for each of the datasets. Sesame calls it context, Jena probably has something equivalent.
5. When querying, try to avoid computationally expensive queries (such as running queries with large number of results and then applying filters). As a rule, try to imagine what the graph pattern would look like for your results and try replicating that in the query.